# Update Microsoft Edge policy without adding management

Tags: google-chrome, plist, microsoft

My workplace internally manages our chrome installation. We have an internal extension store which we're able to install extensions from. This internal extension store is enabled in chrome via the [ExtensionInstallSources](https://chromeenterprise.google/policies/#ExtensionInstallSources) policy. The installation is managed via chef.

We have the freedom to choose our own browser, and I prefer the UI of Microsoft Edge (Chromium). However I'm unable to install extensions from our internal store as Edge does not get installed with the policy setting. the relevant policy reference for Edge is: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/DeployEdge/microsoft-edge-policies#extensioninstallsources

I've added a reference to an internal extension in `/Library/Application Support/Microsoft/Edge/External Extensions`, and I see this gets automatically installed into edge, however remains permanently disabled due to not being from a trusted source.

I've tried manually updating the Info.plist inside the `Microsoft Edge.app` folder like so:

```
        <key>ExtensionInstallSources</key>
        <dict>
            <key>value</key>
            <array>
                <string>https://*.mycompany.com/browser_extensions/*</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
```

including setting relevant `chmod` and `chown` permissions/ownership. The `update.xml` lives at `https://www.mycompany.com/browser_extensions/chrome/update.xml`

This resulted in Edge being unable to launch and I needed to reinstall, and nothing more. I've tried a few other random things here and there which I don't quite recall but haven't had any luck.

Is it possible to set this policy on the application on my machine, without having to go through a company managed installation of the browser?